# Adding minor tick labels to an axis

Tags: bokeh

I'm using Bokeh to plot a histogram, with a logarithmic scale on the x-axis. It looks mostly reasonable, but I'd like to add more tick labels. I found plenty of ways to modify the existing tick labels, but no way to access the minor ticks.

Is there any way to either access the minor ticks, or suggestions of good ways to label more of the ticks in this plot?

Here's my code:

```
p1 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=500, title=target, tools="save", x_axis_type='log', 
            x_range=[10**np.floor(np.log10(min(edges))), 10**np.ceil(np.log10(max(edges)))])

hist, edges = np.histogram(x, bins=hist_bins)
p1.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], 
        alpha=0.8, fill_color='#4c72b0', line_color=None)

p1.xaxis.axis_label = 'Price'
p1.yaxis.axis_label = 'Count'
p1.xgrid.minor_grid_line_color = '#e5e5e5'
p1.xaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0a")
p1.x_range = Range1d(200, 25000)
p1.y_range = Range1d(0, 3000)

output_notebook()
show(p1)
```

And here is an image of current figure in link:

[image: histogram with logarithmic x-axis]

Answer (score 2):

To increase the number of minor ticks, you should be able to do e.g.

```
p.xaxis.ticker.num_minor_ticks = 10
```

There is not currently any built-in support to label minor ticks. If you want more labeled major ticks than are currently drawn, you could try increasing the `desired_num_ticks` value on the ticker as well. However this value is merely a suggestion, and I am not sure how much a log ticker would respect it. (I started to try and test it out but your code sample is not complete and self-contained.) If that does not work I think the only option would be a [Custom Extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) to control the ticking explicitly.

Edit: It's also possible a `FixedTicker` with a `FuncTickFormatter` might be a workable approach as well, but I am not sure how well it could emulate a log axis.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? Using it gives me an attribute error "unexpected attribute 'num_minor_ticks' to LinearAxis".

Comment: It was never valid, the property is on the axis ticker, not the axis itself. I have edited the answer to fix the omission.